# Android disable the function of one layout

Tags: android, layout, scroll, cover

Now I have to create a mask (dark grey transparent layer) which cover the bottom layout (scrollview). So I want to disable the touch function and scroll function of the scrollview.

Now I can place the mask on the bottom layer. But now I can still press the button in scrollview or scroll in the scrollview.

So I have two ideas. The first is to make user touch on the mask and unable to touch the bottom layer, but I have no idea how to do. The second is to disable everything in the bottom layer but I am afraid of scrolling is still possible in the bottom layer.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried the second method, it works but I wonder if there is possible solution like the method one that creating a layer and then cover everything at the back so that disable the touch function of bottom layer

Answer (score 0):

try adding the property below to the mask layout:

```
android:clickable="true"
```